# Flutter web, hide splash screen after flutter web loaded

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

As Flutter web boots up, it may take a few seconds to boot and start to render home page. hence I add an spinner in `index.html` to indicate to the user everything is normal.

in `index.html` (I have simplified)

```
<body>
<div class="spinner"></div>
.
.
.
</body>
```

then I need to listen to an event when `main.dart.js` is completely loaded, to remove the spinner element.
does anyone knows what event I should listen? (I'm talking about javascript events that I can benefit in `index.html`)
I can't listen to `windows.onload` because it fires before flutter boot up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event name is `flutter-first-frame`. add below script in `index.html` which removes and element with id: `spinner` (the loading indicator) when flutter framework completely loaded.

```
<script>
 window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
   var el = document.getElementsByClassName('spinner')[0];
   el.remove();
 });
</script>
```

read more:
https://haashem.medium.com/add-loading-indicator-toflutter-web-653579fe939a

Answer (score 1):

Use the [js](https://pub.dev/packages/js) package to call a js function from Flutter that removes the spinner:

```dart
@JS()
library loading;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS("stopLoading")
external void stopLoading();
```

And in your `index.html`:

```html
<script>
function stopLoading() {
  ...
}
</script>
```